# Storing files on removable sdcard

Tags: android, backup, storage, sd-card

I have two Android apps on the market that read/write from the sdcard.  One of them stores the backup file to the sdcard.  The issue is that with newer smartphones there are two sdcards; the embedded one at /mnt/sdcard and the removable sdcard which doesn't have an standardized directory path.  What I'm hoping to do is add a radio button group with two options for the users; store backup on internal sdcard (default) or store on removable sdcard.  The dilemma is getting the correct path of the removable sdcard and storing that path in a variable.

I've discovered a linux command that seems to work on all android device.  The "df" command lists the location of both the embedded sdcard (/mnt/sdcard) as well as the removable one.  I know how to send commands with the dataoutputstream class but where I'm stuck is reading from the output of the command and filtering just the part I need from the output.

Here's an example of what the output of the "df" command looks like:

```
/ $ df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                   369128        32    369096   0% /dev
tmpfs                   369128         0    369128   0% /mnt/asec
tmpfs                   369128         0    369128   0% /mnt/obb
/dev/block/mmcblk0p1    516040    476832     39208  92% /system
/dev/block/mmcblk0p7  13813852   2948206  10865646  21% /data
/dev/block/mmcblk0p2    533616      8574    525042   2% /cache
tmpfs                   369128         0    369128   0% /Removable
/dev/fuse             13813852   2948206  10865646  21% /mnt/sdcard
/dev/block/vold/179:9 30306304  12222624  18083680  40% /Removable/MicroSD
```

The above output comes from my ASUS Transformer tablet which, as you can see, uses the path /Removable/MicroSD as the directory for the removable sdcard.  Again, all I need to do is grab this output in my code filter out all the unnecessary data and just store the path in a variable.

I'm not looking for someone to write the code for me I just need to find better references to whatever class will allow me to grab the output and filter it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i think this can help private String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + Tags.DIRECTORY_PATH

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately the ExternalStorage class predates smartphones having embedded sdcards and only points to /mnt/sdcard.

Answer (score 2):

i think you have to create your own directory of folder in sd card or internal memory.
like i shown in below.

```
if (sdCardDir != null) 
        return (new File(sdCardDir, CALLHISTORY_FILE).exists());

    ArrayList<File> posibleDir = new ArrayList<File>();
    File esd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    posibleDir.add(new File(esd, "external_sd"));
    posibleDir.add(esd);
    posibleDir.add(new File("/sdcard"));

    // Use first possible sdcard directory
    for (File dir : posibleDir) {
        if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
            sdCardDir = new File(dir, TBACKUP_DIR);
            if(!sdCardDir.exists())
                sdCardDir.mkdir();
            return true;
        }
    }

    throw new IOException();
}
```

Comment: I'm still not clear how that helps me.  The system always assumes that the embedded non-removable sdcard is the right location.  If the device needs to be restored it can cause /mnt/sdard to be wiped in the process which defeats the purpose of the backup.

Comment: Since there's a way to send commands like "df" to the terminal there should be a way to read the output back into the program but so far the only method I've found converts the output into bytes and makes it unreadable.